# How do I add a key file (.key) to my certificate file (.cer) in Keychain Access?

Tags: networking, vpn, certificate, keychain, keychain-access

Trying to add a certificate-key combo (that I downloaded from a colleague) to my Keychain Access so that I can select the certificate file when setting up a new VPN Network in Authentication Settings.

I can add the certificate but Keychain is saying it's not trusted and I'm not sure how to associate it with its corresponding .key file. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the key via the Command Line with

```
security import mykey.key -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain
```

And then renamed the key in KeyChain Access to match my certificate.